# I'm trying to Search a text document for Book and verse

Tags: text-processing

I have multiple documents with references to multiple Bible books and verses on my Ubuntu machine. I want to create a list showing the book name chapter number and verse or verses. A typical entry in the document would be `Matt 12:1` or `John 9: 4-9`.

The list should contain `Matt 12:1` with page numbers if possible and how many times it was found in the document. I have a script that I use to create a txt file with a list of all words. I have never used `grep` previously so I'm totally lost.

Here is what I have working for the word list:

```
cat exported.txt | grep -o -E '\w+' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c >preconcordance.txt
```

Snippet with several examples:

> The Scriptures reveal it's the sons of Jerusalem (John 6:43-47, Isa 54:11, 13), and it's these sons who serve God (Mal 3:17-18). and These two cities are examples of what happens to those who suffer death by eternal fire. Peter wrote: 2Pet 2:6 .. The ABYSS is where the most wicked of all demons are imprisoned (2Pet 2:4, Jude 1:6, Rev 9:1). For a further explanation of this place of restraint, see Luke 8:31, and note that Christ had the power to send these demons to the ABYSS.

**Edit**

To rephrase my question: is it possible to look for text and numbers in parentheses. If all my book name chapter and verse references are included as `(2Pet 1:2-3)`. I have seen some examples similar but could not make them work. totally out of my league at this point.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the documents? (you can [edit] the post) I assume you have other text there too, like the actual text of the referenced passages, right?

Comment: also references like "John 1–3; 3:16; 6:14, 44" would be rather interesting, if there's any of those in there (also a minor question of if the dash should be the regular ASCII dash, or e.g. the Unicode EN DASH the Wikipedia page I copied that from had)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you would like to see from that example input.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = slurp.split(". "); my @b = @a.match(:global, / "(" ~ ")" .+? / ).join;  \
         @b.=split(/ \,\s* || <[()]> /, :skip-empty); .say for @b.map(*.tc).Bag.sort(-*.value);'
```

Sample Input (note OP's first reference has been duplicated and lowercased):

```
The Scriptures reveal it's the sons of Jerusalem (John 6:43-47, Isa 54:11, 13), (john 6:43-47), and it's these sons who serve God (Mal 3:17-18). and These two cities are examples of what happens to those who suffer death by eternal fire. Peter wrote: 2Pet 2:6 .. The ABYSS is where the most wicked of all demons are imprisoned (2Pet 2:4, Jude 1:6, Rev 9:1). For a further explanation of this place of restraint, see Luke 8:31, and note that Christ had the power to send these demons to the ABYSS.
```

Sample Output:

```
John 6:43-47 => 2
Jude 1:6 => 1
Rev 9:1 => 1
Isa 54:11 => 1
Mal 3:17-18 => 1
13 => 1
2Pet 2:4 => 1
```

Raku is a member of the Perl-family of programming languages, and it's a good choice here--especially if you anticipate wrangling Unicode text such as Greek or [Hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540269/7270649) characters (Raku handles Unicode by default).

Briefly, the file is `slurp`ed (read in all at once) and (destructively) `split` on "`.` " period-space, to break the text into sentences. These elements are stored in the `@a` array. In the second statement the `@a` array is tested for `match`es to the `"(" ~ ")" .+?` regex, which is Raku's way of finding parenthesized text ( the `"(" .+? ")"` regex also works, but see explanation regarding [nested structures](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex__tilde-_regex__%7E-Tilde_for_nesting_structures)). These matches are `join`ed (essentially removing blank elements) and assigned to the `@b` array.

In the third statement the parenthesized text is again (destructively) `split`, this time on either `\,\s*` comma-followed-by-optional-whitespace, or `<[()]>` a custom character class created with the `<[`…`]>` markers and consisting of either `(` or `)`. Note, in this case `split(… , :skip-empty)` is used, which removes blank elements. These results are `.=` assigned back to the `@b` array ( `@b.=split(…)` is syntactic sugar for `@b = @b.split(…)` ).

Finally in the fourth statement, `map(*.tc)` elements of `@b` are converted to titlecase, `Bag`-ged (see [here](https://docs.raku.org/type/Bag)), and `sort`ed by `-*.value` (decreasing value). Output is produced linewise using `.say for` … .

It's easy enough to swap keys and values, and switch around the output columns (as well as sort order). Changing the final `.say` to `.put` removes the `=>` arrow from the output, leaving two columns separated by a `\t` tab-space.

https://raku.org